# Can we have a canonical "One beginner design question to [link to] them all"?

Tags: discussion

We've got loads of great Q&A content for beginners. We also get loads of beginners asking similar "where to start" type questions. It's time consuming to always say "read this and this and this" then trying to remember them all, fighting through search and a thicket of links to find them.

Can we make, community-wiki-answer, then either protect or close as too broad a Q&A combo where the question is the most broad possible **"Design beginner, where do I start?"** and the answer is a big structured sectioned list of our quality beginner resources?

Then every broad newbie question, we either say "you might find this useful" and link to it if it's not a dupe, or if it's already covered, we dupe it to this one.

Listing questions such as:

- [Coming from a programming background, where should I start to learn web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/)
- The "I'm an artist, how do I become a designer" question
- The "do I need a design degree to do good design" question
- [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)
- [How do I learn to be creative?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative)
- Maybe a tools section with:

  - the "which adobe application does what" question
  - the "what cheap/free adobe alternatives are there" question
  - the "mac vs pc" question
- Maybe a careers section with:

  - The spec work question
  - The "how to build a portfolio" question
  - The "how to price" question
- Maybe an essential knowledge section with

  - The RGB vs CMYK question
  - The PPI explained question

You get the idea... The GD.SE graphic design syllabus.

Comment: This is exactly what's needed imo. +100. Yisela once suggested having separate answers for subjects, and then the accepted answer pointing to each subject (so that an answer can be accepted) on my key design principles question. I never got around to doing it, but it may be useful here.

Comment: Excellent idea! :D

Comment: Great idea! I will help as much as I can!